# $location.path get me previous path

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url-routing, angular-ui-router

I'm new in angularjs and I want to get current state url but when i use `$location.path()` function its give me last state that i click on it for example in this plunker that i made when i click on dashboard at first i get empty string after i click on accounts and after i click dashboard it get me the name url of accounts `(/view1)` instead of `(/view2)` why this is occur?
this is my plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/EHkgk0x48JsrNeX2FqgG?p=preview

Comment: Why did you not posted your code here?

Comment: why i most post it here?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help __("why isn't this code working?")__ must include the desired behaviour, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce __it in the question itself.__ Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: other peaple easily understand what i say, i choose best answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your `reloading()` function is processed on the url that you clicked the button on. only after that it goes to the next page. so it will not write the location of the next page.

say, for example:

you click on Dashboard, it logs empty string.

you click on accounts, it does not do anything as click handler is not specified.

Now, your current url is `/view1`
when you click on Dashboard, the `reloading` function is called, it logs the current url , which is `/view1` and then navigates to the new url `/view2`.

P.S: Try this:

click on dashboard, it will log empty string.
Now, your current url in `/view2`
click on dashboard again, it will log `/view2`

Answer (score 2):

This occur because you call `reloading` function inside `ng-click` before the actual route changes.

Change your controller like:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', function($scope, $location){ 

    // Fired when the transition begins. 
    $scope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){ 
      console.log("State changed: " +  $location.path())
    })

    // Fired on click:
    $scope.reloading = function(){
      console.log("On click: " + $location.path())
    }

}]);
```

and observe the output in the console - I guess you will get better understanding of what is happening this way.

Comment: but when I call reloading function we are in /view2 state i can not understand why? can u explain more?

Comment: I am not sure I understand you. I've actually just answered your question.